# Speed up lattice plots by reusing old plot parameters?

Tags: r, performance, plot, lattice

I'm doing some exploratory analyses on large data sets (~10,000 data points grouped into ~ten curves). I am using the [`manipulate`](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/manipulate) package in RStudio to change the x-axis limits. The problem is that it can take 5+ seconds for the plot to be redrawn with the new parameters. I am hoping for a way to speed this up just a little bit. I'm using the `lattice` package. Here is a simplified example...

```
set.seed(100)
x = rep(1:5,20)
y = rnorm(100)
groups = gl(20,5)
p = xyplot(y~x,groups=groups,type="l",
           auto.key=list(space="right",lines=TRUE,
                         points=TRUE,rectangles=TRUE) )

Rprof(interval=0.001)
print(p)
Rprof(NULL)
head( summaryRprof()$by.total )
                  total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"print"                0.239    100.00     0.000     0.00
"printFunction"        0.239    100.00     0.000     0.00
"print.trellis"        0.239    100.00     0.000     0.00
"do.call"              0.126     52.72     0.001     0.42
"draw.key"             0.098     41.00     0.001     0.42
"evaluate.legend"      0.098     41.00     0.000     0.00
```

Note that `draw.key` takes 41% of the run time (and yes, this superfluous legend was chosen to emphasize my point). For my purposes, my legend will never change but the plot will. Is there then a way to save the legend, key, or anything from one plot and reuse it over and over again (perhaps reuse the `Grob` object from `lattice::draw.key`)? I have looked into some of the code for `lattice:::plot.trellis` and it looks like there should be a way to do this. However, it looks like it would take a significant amount of new code to do so. Is there a simple solution? Alternatively, are there any other plotting functions or packages that are known for their speed? I can of course fit smooth curves to my data to "compress/downsample" it, but I'd rather not do this.

Comment: Any update?  Did you try plotting to a file?

Comment: Plotting to a file works OK, but this get's rid of the interactivity that I wanted. I am really trying to find a solution that stays in the R output device. I'd imagine printing to a file that automatically updates on my screen (e.g., printing to a PDF that automatically updates in a pdf reader) would be an adequate solution if I simply wanted to reduce the time of plotting. Perhaps this would be especially relevant for plots that take 20 seconds or so to plot. However, my plots take about 5 seconds and the annoyance of accessing another file is about equal to that of waiting the 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, there are ways to speed up the printing of a lattice plot based on pre-computed grid objects or other parameters. However, as far as I know, there is no simple solution. To do so, I was required to delve into the source of the lattice plotting function `plot.trellis` to identify spots where I could optimize speed. Continuing from the example in the question...

```
# Save the legend from the last plot
plot.grob = trellis.last.object()
legend.grob = lattice:::evaluate.legend( plot.grob$legend )

# Modify the default plotting function
f = lattice:::plot.trellis
b = body(f)
fun.line = which(!is.na(str_match(as.character(b),"evaluate.legend")))
new.line = substitute(legend <- if(is.null(legend.object)) 
                        evaluate.legend(x$legend) else legend.object)
body(f)[[fun.line]] = new.line
args = formals(f)
formals(f) = do.call(alist, c( args[2:length(args)-1], alist(legend.object=NULL,...=)) )

# Note that evaluate.legend is no longer taking up any time because it's not called
Rprof()
f(plot.grob,legend.object=legend.grob)
Rprof(NULL)
head(summaryRprof()$by.total)

# the modified function is faster
times = data.frame( modified.fun=NA, standard.fun=NA )
for( i in 1:100 ) {
  t1 = profr( f(plot.grob,legend.object=legend.grob), interval=0.001 )[1,"time"]
  t2 = profr( plot(plot.grob), interval=0.001 )[1,"time"]
  times = rbind( times, c( t1, t2 ) )
}
colMeans(na.omit(times))
modified.fun standard.fun 
     0.11435      0.19757
```

My modified function takes about 40% less time, which makes sense since the `evaluate.legend` call takes about 40% of the run time in the `plot.trellis` example given in the question. There were also many other spots in the `plot.trellis` function where I could optimize speed. If one were to keep going, they could eventually get the function down to the bare bones so that the only the functions from the `grid` package are being called. This would essentially be rewriting an entirely new `plot.trellis` function with reduced flexibility but better speed. However, this is not what I wanted.

On a side note, I noticed that the actual drawing of a plot on my screen takes longer than the run time reported by the profiling code. I used a stopwatch to time that it took a little less than 1 second longer for the plot to show up after the code was reported to be done running. I tried with other plotting packages that also rely on `grid` and found similar results. So, no matter how well a plotting function is optimized, I decided that either `grid`, base R, or my hardware eventually become the limiting factor when I get down to times of 1 second or less. There are solutions for this new problem but that's another topic...

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes find that it's faster to plot to a file than to the screen and then open the file.

That's not what you're looking for, but if it would be fast enough, it would be a whole lot simpler...